# Correct format for a command in Codenvy

Tags: bash, terminal, command, codenvy

Codenvy is an IDE that removes all files that are in gitignore when the environment you work in goes to sleep. So every time I start working in Codenvy I need to put these files back. That is a hassle and therefore I am trying to add what in Codenvy is called a command (a script) for this.

I have the following:

```
1. cp vars-user-portal/variables.env user-portal/variables.env
2.
3. cp vars-user-portal/serviceAccountKey.json user-portal/serviceAccountKey.json
4.
5. cp vars-user-portal/.env user-portal/client/.env
6.
7. cd user-portal && npm install
8.
9. cd user-portal/client && npm install
10.
11. xdg-open user-portal/client/.env
```

[image: Codenvy command]

When I run this command, I get the output:

```
/bin/bash: line 1: $'\r': command not found
/bin/bash: line 3: $'\r': command not found
/bin/bash: line 5: $'\r': command not found

Usage: npm <command>
...
Did you mean one of these?
    install
    uninstall
    unstar

/bin/bash: line 7: $'\r': command not found

Usage: npm <command>
...

/bin/bash: line 9: $'\r': command not found
xdg-open: file '.env' does not exist
```

I have the impression that when there are spaces on a line it sees it as separate commands. Any idea how I can get this script to work?

Comment: Check your file for special characters: `cat -A file` or `cat -v file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file most likely has `\r\n` line endings, which should be changed to `\n` line endings.

A simple way to convert the file with the command line `sed` utility is as follows.

`sed -i 's/\r\n/\n/g' "./path/to/file"` (Untested).

---

In general, Windows applications terminate lines in text files with the 'carriage return' and 'line feed' characters, commonly written as the escape codes `\r\n`.

On the other hand, Unix-like systems terminate lines with only the line feed, or new as a line ending, which Unix uses just 'line feed' character `\n`.

See: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html

---

Note:

As an additional mention, you should always add a shebang to the top of your script if it is to be executable, or else do not add one if it is to be solely sourced. `#!/bin/bash` for bash scripts, and `#!/bin/sh` for portable or POSIX-compliant scripts.

Comment: Not sure I understand. It's not a separate file I have. These commands are part of Codenvy and the exact content is in my Original Post. I've also added a screenshot now.

Comment: @Nick It has been a while since I have used Codeenvy, and I have very limited experience with it, though, `\r` is certainly almost always the return character escape code. The output you posted is what is printed with the issue I described. Not that you will not be able to see the line ending escape codes as they are purposely not rendered by the editor. Notice that any typical text editor allows for the creation of a new line, and since the data is stared in a continuous string, there needs to be a reserved code to signify the newline.

Comment: @Nick As for the Codenvy context, I am not sure, though look for a setting where line endings can be specified, which should be set to `lf` [line feed] as opposed to `crlf` [carriage return and line feed] to result in `\n` line endings. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Nick Another possible issue, though I would say it would be unlikely, is that you may have pasted the commands in along with the `crlf` line endings. This could be fixed by converting the line endings externally to `lf`, then pasting once again.

If any of these thoughts I have commented solve your problem, let me know so I may add to my answer. Cheers.

Comment: I found a workaround: if I just put it all on one line with && between them, then it works. So yes, you're absolutely right in the cause, so I have accepted your answer. How to more nicely remedy this in Codenvy, instead of this workaround, I don't know.